# Best Multi-threaded Architecture for an Retriving Data Over HTTP?

Tags: android, android-service

world!

I'm building an application that has to retrieve data from a server in several different `Activity`s.  Some data is cached to a SQLite database (and retrieved from there instead in future), and some must be called fresh from the server every time.  I need to know what the best multi-threaded architecture would be for this application.  Multiple `Activity`s will be connecting to the server.

I'm thinking a bound `Service` would be best, but of course I'm not sure.  If that's the way to go, how exactly do I implement multi-threading in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android classes such as IntentService and AsynTask are thread safest because they will not keep your activity open when your activity's finish method is called. If you create your own Thread implementation you must remember to stop the thread on Activity finish so that the process' memory will be reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like yours I am going with a set of singleton factory classes to access local SQLite db and a background service doing asynchronous replication